# Decode Feedly JSON data

Tags: json, xcode, nsdictionary

I currently have the code below to decode some received JSON data. However, since Feedly doesn't give any indexes back I don't know how to properly decode the JSON data. This is an example of JSON I receive back:

```
[
  {
    "id": "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/tech",
    "label": "tech"
  },
  {
    "id": "user/c805fcbf-3acf-4302-a97e-d82f9d7c897f/category/design",
    "label": "design"
  }
]
```

And if I let the code below run, the `NSLog` outputs it perfectly. But how do I fetch the `label` variables from `res`?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of notifications",[self.responseData length]);

    // convert to JSON
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    NSLog(@"res value contains: %@", res);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If short to get `label` values use `[res valueForKeyPath:@"label"];`

But to make it work in right way you need to change type of res to `NSArray` because provided JSON contains array of dictionary.

Then you can traverse through with for-in.

```
NSError *myError = nil;
    NSArray *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
for (NSDictionary *d in res) {
    NSLog(@"label %@",[d objectForKey:@"label"]);
}
    NSLog(@"res value contains: %@", res);
```